# I would like to have a spanish/english link on a master page that will take you to the current page in the other language and not to the 'home' page

Tags: javascript, .net, html, master-pages

I have a Visual Studio C# .NET project. I have two master templates. One for the original website in english. And a second master page for the Spanish version of the website.
In both master pages, there's a link that says "English" (or Spanish). This link will take the user to the translation of the website in the other language.

But If I am in the "About Us" page in english, and I click in the SPANISH link, it will take me to the Home Page in spanish and not to the current page (in this case About Us) in spanish. How can I set the Link in the master page, to know what page translation i want ?

I have no idea how to code this thing.

Thanks.

**SOLUTION - SOLVED**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function SetLanguageLinkUrl() {
            var url = location.href;
            var newURL;

         // Create block of these, for each set of pages in different languages.
                if (url.indexOf("inicio") > 0)
                newURL = url.replace("/es/inicio.aspx", "/en/index.aspx");
                else if (url.indexOf("index") > 0)
                    newURL = url.replace("/en/index.aspx", "/es/inicio.aspx");

        // The Redirect
            window.location = newURL;

    }
</script>
```

Comment: How are you denoting the current language? On the QueryString? Using a language folder (e.g. /en/about-us) ?

Comment: using a language folder /es/filename.aspx.  I have two master pages, main.master and spanish.master... the main.master has a link to the /es/index.aspx  but I would like that link to take me to the 'current page' in the other language. So If I'm in Contact Us, I want it to take me to Contacto.aspx instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an [`HtmlAnchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) in your masterpage, you could replace the language folder in the link with the other language folder in your url.

```
void SetLanguageLinkUrl()
{
     string url = Request.Url.PathAndQuery.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();
     if(url.StartsWith("/en/"))
         languageLink.HRef = url.Replace("/en/", "/es/");
     else if(url.StartsWith("/es/"))
         languageLink.HRef = url.Replace("/es/", "/en/");
}
```

### UPDATE

If you want to translate the url, you're maybe best having a dictionary of urls to use as a lookup table.

Comment: This is what I have in the master.page : <div style="text-align:right; font-family: Trebuchet MS; font-size:13px; 
<a style="color: #ffffff;" href="../es/inicio.aspx">ESPAÑOL</div>

Comment: Give it a try and see if it makes sense to you

Comment: but that doesn't look like it would take me from about.aspx to acerca.aspx , or from contact.aspx to contacto.aspx , it looks like it takes me to the main page of the folder in the other language. I am looking forward to have the current page (the one im currently browsing right now) click in the other language and have that same page in spanish.

Comment: Like something that would redirect contact.aspx to contacto.aspx , but the issue is that i have to do it in the master template, and i don't know how to do that. As opposed to taking me from contact.aspx (in english) to /es/ (which would be the default.aspx) ...

Comment: So if the current url is `/en/about.aspx` the link will be set to `/es/about.aspx`. You didn't mention you wanted to translate the URL. as I say, try it to see the logic

Comment: BTW I used your idea, in a different way : I added javascript in the head of the document and this helped me out a lot. I will add the solution in a bit. Thanks !